# Why is the restoring torque of a wire dominated by the shear modulus and not the stress?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science, oscillators

I have been looking into different suspensions for a torsional pendulum setup, and came across this paper by Quinn comparing (round) wires and (ribbon) strips.

You can find the article at doi: 10.1088/0026-1394/34/3/6

In equation (2) in the paper, the torsional constant of a round wire is given as:

$$ c_w = \frac{\pi r^4}{2L}\left(F + \frac{Mg}{\pi r^2}\right) $$

where, $r$ is the radius of the wire, $L$, the length, $M$, the mass of the load, and $F$ is the shear modulus of the suspension material.

They then mention that the stress term ${Mg}/{\pi r^2}$ is always much smaller than $F$ and therefore the restoring torque of a wire is always dominated by the elastic component.

This is the part that I have a bit of trouble understanding. Consider, $M = 2$ kg, $r = 30$ $\mu$m, $F = 53$ MPa $= 5.3 \times 10^{7}$ N/m$^2$

These values were approximated from the experimental values described in the paper

Then, ${Mg}/{\pi r^2} \approx 2 \times 10^{11}$ N/m$^2$

This is clearly larger than the shear modulus term, contrary to the previous statement about the elastic component always being the dominating factor. Can some please explain where I might be going wrong here? Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radius of 30 $\mu$m is very small for a wire to be used in an ordinary experiment, for example in an undergraduate laboratory. You can easily show that if a 2.0 kg load could be hung from it, the tensile stress would be about 7 GN m$^{-2}$. [I don't know how you arrive at your figure of $2\times 10^{11}\text{N m}^{-2}$ for $mg/\pi r^2$; I make it 7 GN m$^{-2}$ for $r=30\ \mu\text {m and}\ M=2.0\ \text{kg}$.] The ultimate tensile stress for copper is around 0.2 GN m$^{-2}$, and of steels, only some special types will withstand 7 GN m$^{-2}$, so you wouldn't normally be able to make such a thin wire support a 2 kg load.

With a more practicable radius of wire – let's say 300 $\mu$m – we have $mg/\pi r^2 = 0.07\ \text{GN m}^{-2}$, and that is pretty negligible compared with a shear modulus of 50 GN m$^{-2}$, the figure for copper.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. The 200  GN m$^{-2}$ was a miscalculation on my part, it should indeed be 7 GN  m$^-2$. I think I confused myself by using the thickness value they used for their torsional strip, and not realizing that the tensile stress term is limited by the ultimate tensile strength. But it all makes sense now. The torsional strip can of course still be 30 um because the they use a width on the order of 1 mm, which ends up lowering the effective tensile stress.